# To read CSV (html) content

Tags: csv

## I have CSV file say:

```
col1,col2
ABCD,<p>Its Awesome ,I want to fly..</p>
```

(col1 having some string,col2 html content)

I want to insert col1 & col2 data in database. When I read file using csv my data is col2(

Its Awesome ,I want to fly..

) data is split into two and only 

Its Awesome

 is inserted in database.
I am trying a way in which before passing the actually file with comma it is seperated by some charater .
Please advise as to how html content can be read.

Answer (score 1):

It's splitting on the extra comma.  You need to quote the fields in your csv.  I have no idea what you're parsing with but it should handle this case:

```
col1,col2
ABCD,"<p>Its Awesome ,I want to fly..</p>"
```

or alternatively

```
col1,col2
ABCD,<p>Its Awesome ","I want to fly..</p>
```

Comment: I dont think my customer will take pains to add quote for every record.I have comma as seperator

Comment: Then your task is impossible unless it's always the last field that can have unquoted and unescaped delimiters in it.